# induction for finite cases from 1 to n. How is this possible?

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

hi guys I have a question.

> SECOND PROOF. We will repeat the argument, but without the trees.
> Consider an arbitrary wff α. It is the last member of some construction sequence ε1,...,εn
> . By ordinary strong numerical induction on the number i, we see that each εi ∈ S, i ≤ n.
> That is, we suppose, as our inductive hypothesis, that ε j ∈ S
> for all j < i. We then verify that εi ∈ S, by considering the
> various cases. So by strong induction on i, it follows that εi ∈ S
> for each i ≤ n. In particular, the last member α belongs to S.

this is the example from the book mathematical introduction to logic by herbert enderton.

Usually, the case of using induction or strong induction is to prove the property P for all natural numbers. But this example uses induction for finite cases from 1 to n. How is this possible?

Comment: WFF = well-formed formula?

Comment: If you want to prove property P for all n less than N prove $Q(n)=P(n)\vee n\geq N$ holds for all n by induction as usual.

Comment: (often P does not even make sense for all n, but then you can define Q by pieces, like you do in calculus to define this sign function)

Comment: Why *shouldn't* induction work for finite cases? The principal is the same.  If $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ and $P(1)$ is true, it follows for all values because you start at one, and do the next and so on.  The only differences is that for a finite case we can make a slight restriction do $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ *up to $k < n$*.  So you have it in the condition you stop at $n$.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Note:  the condition "for each $\epsilon_i; i\le n$.  That means we stop at $n$.

Comment: Consider I wanted to prove by induction that **IF $k<10$ then  $\underbrace{111....1}_k^2 = 123.....(k-1)k(k-1)....21$.  Our base step is trivial: $1^1=1$.  Our induction step: assume for some $k<10$ that $111....1 = 123...k...321$.  Then if $k+1< 10$ we have $1111...1^2 = (11111...10 + 1)^2 = 1111...10^2 + 22222....20 + 1 = 1234....k(k-1)(k-2)...100+2222....21 = 1234....k(k-1+2)(k-2+2)(k-3+2).....(1+2)(0+2)(0+1)-1234....(k+1)....1$.  This works.  It's fine.

Comment: @BrianTung yes!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do induction for a finite number of $n$ cases make your Property statement be:  P(k) is "If $k\le n$ than $Q(k)$"

Then when you do induction proof you will have proven that for *all* natural numbers $m$, that  ***if***  $m \le n$ then $Q(m)$.  The thing is that as $m\le n$ for only $0,....m$ we don't have to worry about the rest.

And if you are worried about how "If $k \le n$" will effect your induction step, well, don't worry.  This is what happens:

Induction step:  Assume $P(k)$ that is assume if $k \le n$ then $Q(k)$.  We need to prove that if $k+1 \le n$ then $Q(k)$.  If $k+1 > n$ then we are done and have nothing to prove.  And if $k+1\le n$ we .... do our induction step just like normal.

That condition doesn't hurt us in any way.